# Path for the liveness/readiness probe for the Airflow Webserver pod

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm

Airflow is running on the Azure Kubernetes Service.
I have used the [official helm](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-airflow/airflow/1.7.0) chart version 1.7.0 for the installation.
Now I am trying to figure out how to set up path for liveness/readiness probe for webserver.

The point is that Airflow doesn't have main domain name in our infrastructure. We are using sub path for it: maindomain.ch/airflow/

And the difficulty is that it is impossible to specify path for the liveness/readiness probe for the main webserver pod. Only for some extraContainers. Has anyone faced the same issue? Or is it part of design?